Uniform convergence of a sequence of polynomials on the unit circle
Let $(P_n)_n$ be a sequence of polynomials in one variable with complex coefficients. Assume that $(|P_n|)_n$ converges uniformly to $1$ on the unit circle (concretely, the supremum of $| |P_n(z)|-1|$ on $|z|=1$ goes to $0$ as $n\to +\infty$). Do we have
(1)  Max { $|a_{0,n}|, \dots, |a_{d_n,n}|$ } $\to 1$
as $n\to +\infty$, where $a_{0,n},\dots, a_{d_n,n}$ denotes the coefficients of $P_n$ ?
Remark 1 : If $|P_n|=1$ on the unit circle for some $n$, then $P_n$ is a monomial and its unique coefficient has absolute value $1$. That's why I'm wondering if the uniform convergence assumption implies (1).
Remark 2 : We have $\sum_{m=0}^{d_n} |a_{m,n}|^2 = \int_{|z|=1} | P_n(z) |^2 dz \to 1$. Thus, if (1) holds to be true, then all other coefficients go to $0$.
Thanks in advance,
Arnaud

The result doesn't hold. Take $f(z)=\frac{2z-1}{2-z}$ which satisfies $||f||_{\infty}=1$ but its Taylor coefficients are clearly all non zero by direct computation using the geometric series for the denominator.
Then take $P_n$ the $n$th truncation which clearly converges uniformly and absolutely on the closed unit disc so $||P_n-f||_{\infty} \to 0$ hence by the triangle inequality we get $||P_n||-||f||\to 0$ or $||P_n|| \to 1$.
But the coefficients of $P_n$ are those of $f$ up to $z^n$ by definition and as noted those are just all nonzero numbers (the maximum above is $3/4$ for all $n\ge 1$)
